# How to get full details from Firebase database using rest client Api

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, get, rest-client

I have a firebase database that looks like below

[image]

I am using rest-client API to get data from the firebase in Unity c#. I know how to call one user at a time using rest-client API.

```
RestClient.Get<User>(databaseURL + "/" + getLocalId + ".json?auth=" + idToken).Then(response =>
            {
              
            });
```

But I want to know how to call/download all users using one request, but also avoiding one column, that is Project column as shown in the below picture. How to do this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend you use the unity SDK as its better for performance and usage optimization check firebase documentation on this matter here

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/optimize#open-connections
```

as for your question when you get data from parent level you get its children nodes with it so when you get the data at path users you will get all the users data under it but if you get the data at users/uid path you get that specific user (node) only so you can’t really get all users without getting the projects of each user too as the projects are a child node

a workaround could be having two different data paths the one you already have users/uid/data but without including the projects list under users
the second one projects/uid/data
this way when you pull users data you will not get projects data as it does not contain it and if you want projects list of certain user you can still get by the user id just from different path projects/uid instead of users/uid